# java 8 stream for double loop and change the value in first loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

i have nested loop to loop and change the first list based on condition below. this works fine.

its like if cardNumber in firstList same or found in secondList, copy properties from secondList to firstList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listFirst.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < listSecond.size(); j++) {
        if (StringUtils.equals(listFirst.get(i).getCardNumber(), listSecond.get(j).getCardNumber())) {
            try {
                 listFirst.get(i).setSubmitDate(listSecond.get(j).getIssueDate());
                 listFirst.get(i).setPersonalNumber(listSecond.get(j).getPersonalNumber());
                 listFirst.get(i).setMembershipPeriod(listSecond.get(j).getPeriod());
                 listFirst.get(i).setPhoneNumber(listSecond.get(j).getMobileNo());
                 listFirst.get(i).setIdCardNumber(listSecond.get(j).getIdNumber());
                 listFirst.get(i).setMoney(listSecond.get(j).getLoanAmount().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    }
}
```

i just want to know is this possible in java 8 stream? or lambda expression? i've tried using stream, for each, but sometimes i got confused.

Comment: Might not be an issue if lists are small, but instead of comparing all elements in both lists (O(n*m)) you could create a Map mapping card ids to items, then get matching items from the Map (O(n+m)).

Comment: Also, instead of using streams, just using "enhanced for loops" `for (ClassName item1 : listFirst) {...` would already make the code much cleaner.

Comment: if i use enchanced for , i cannot change the first list element.

Comment: You can not change the value assigned to the variable (`item1` in my example), but you can set attributes, e.g. `item1.setSubmitDate(item2.getIssueDate());`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Foo` is your class, we can form a cartesian product of items of the 2 lists, and then filter by some property (cardNumber equality). Then, matching pairs can be used in a `forEach` stream-terminating method.

```java
listFirst.stream()
   .flatMap(t -> listSecond.stream().map(s -> new Foo[] {t, s}))
   .filter(pair -> StringUtils.equals(pair[0].getCardNumber(), pair[1].getCardNumber()))
   .forEach(pair -> {
       final Foo t = pair[0], s = pair[1]; // unpack pair
       // set individual properties here (or call a setup method) ...
       t.setSubmitDate(s.getIssueDate())
       // .... more sets ...
   })
```

Answer (score -1):

With a little reorganization, yes:

If you were to add a method to the class in the first list to do the checks and assignments:

```
public void init(YourClass other) {
    if (StringUtils.equals(getCardNumber(), other.getCardNumber())) {
        try {
             setSubmitDate(other.getIssueDate());
             setPersonalNumber(other.getPersonalNumber());
             setMembershipPeriod(other.getPeriod());
             setPhoneNumber(other.getMobileNo());
             setIdCardNumber(other.getIdNumber());
             setMoney(other.getLoanAmount().toString());
         } catch (Exception e) {
             log.error(e.getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```

Then your loop can become:

```
listFirst.stream()
         .forEach(a -> listSecond.stream()
                                 .forEach(b -> a.init(b)));
```

Comment: No need for a stream over the list, `listFirst.forEach(…)` will work too

Comment: I think it would make much more sense to have a `filter` in the stream than an `if` in the `init` method...

Comment: ohhh yeah, this works too. since i dont want to make method in my pojo class. i make method direct in .foreach. thanks for your suggestion. nice.